# Rails + rubygems + rvm disaster/confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm not sure exactly what I did but I messed up the Ruby/gem harmony trying to get an older 2.3.5 Rails app working on my system.

I'm currently using Ruby 1.9.2-p0 and rubygems 1.5.7. I've tried the newest one 1.8.2 but it just generates more warnings. I use these alongside of RVM.

I get "can't convert Symbol into Integer" when trying to boot a 2.3.x Rails app no matter what version of rubygems I run. I tried 1.5.7, 1.7.2, and 1.8.2.

```
$ script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
path/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:51:in `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

Any idea how I can get my system back in harmony?

Comment: You may have to downgrade to ruby 1.8.7. 1.9.2 is not backwards compatible. `rvm install 1.8.7`

Comment: Rubygems 1.8.2 does generate warnings, but it's a temporary problem if you run `gem update --system` followed by `gem pristine --all --no-extensions`, followed by `gem list` and noting which, if any, have a warning. For each of those do a `gem uninstall` followed by a `gem install`. That should clean up the problem.

Comment: @Dex - I installed 1.8.7-p334 and have it running in a terminal window alongside 1.9.2-p180. Rails 3 runs fine with 1.9.2 and rails 2 runs fine on 1.8.7. Much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @the Tin Man - Your gem pristine command works great to remove those errors! Many thanks to you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As Dex and The Tin Man suggested in the comments, the solution was to run rails 2 on ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3 on ruby 1.9.2 using vrm. The warnings generated by rubygems 1.8.2 (now 1.8.3) are solved by running his suggest commands.